# Azure AD PowerShell (Cloud): Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: azure-active-directory, appsource

I'm trying to use the Azure AD PowerShell to generate an invite link. I'm using the New-AzureADMSInvitation method (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureadmsinvitation?view=azureadps-2.0).

I run it in the cloud shell and get the following error:

```
PS Azure:\> New-AzureADMSInvitation

cmdlet New-AzureADMSInvitation at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
InvitedUserEmailAddress: "**@**.com"
InviteRedirectUrl: "**.com"
New-AzureADMSInvitation : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureADMSInvitation
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureADMSInvitation], NullReferenceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NullReferenceException,Microsoft.Open.MSGraphV10.PowerShell.NewAzureADMSInvitation
```

I've tried restarting the shell, not including the quotes in the inputs, but no luck. Anyone able to get around this?

Comment: Are you able to run this in your own machine instead of cloud shell?

Comment: I used the cloud shell because I don't have a windows machine. I tried the OSx and Linux PowerShell installs before using the cloud shell, but they didn't have the New-AzureADMSInvitiation functionality. Looks like I'll need to track down a windows OS or use a VM, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like we cannot use this command in Cloud Shell (Powershell). I also suggest you can post your idea in [this Feedback Forum](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/598699-azure-cloud-shell). Azure Team will review it.

Also, you can try to use this powershell command on your local machine .
Ensure you have used [AAD Powershell 2.0 or later](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/install-adv2?view=azureadps-2.0).

Just try to Enter the following powershell scripts:

`New-AzureADMSInvitation -InvitedUserEmailAddress <guest user's EmailAddress> -SendInvitationMessage $True -InviteRedirectUrl "http://myapps.onmicrosoft.com"`

Hope this helps!